# Keras: ModelCheckpoint save to variable instead of file?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I want to train my model for X epochs and obtain the best result in terms of minimal validation error.

The solution I found was to use the ModelCheckpoint callback which can be configured to override a model save if the result of the current epoch was better.

However, in worst case scenario, this means in each epoch a model is written to the hard drive, which generates a huge time overhead.

Is there a possibility to save the model to a variable instead so I need to save it only one time? Or is there another optimization I can do?

Comment: You can always create your own callback implementation that does what you want.

Comment: That is true. If there is no other solution this might be what I will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docstring of [save_model](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/saving.py#L452), the path can also be a `h5py.File` object, and there is [an example of in-memory files](https://www.pytables.org/cookbook/inmemory_hdf5_files.html#creating-a-new-file-in-memory) in the h5py documentation.

Comment: I tried passing a h5py file object as parameter but the modelCheckpoint callback does only want a filepath string as parameter: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py

Comment: You can write your own callback, it won't be much work

Comment: I implemented a custom solution now and it works. Not as much of a time saver as I expected, though. Seems like the saving process was already relatively fast.